# jScrollPane setting a padding-bottom value

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

For layout purposes I need to place 15px space between the bottom of the scrolled contents and the bottom of the container: `div class="scroll-pane"`.

Styling the container `.scroll-pane { padding-bottom:15px; }` has no influence on the output. Going into the code of plugin jScrollPane(), it is set: `elem.css({'padding':0});` so the padding-value is reset.

Is there any way to set a paddingBottom value for the scrolling container?

Answer (score 1):

A css rule should work too!

```
.scroll-pane {
  padding-bottom:15px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery

```
$('.scroll-pane').parent().css('padding-bottom', '15px');
```

Should do the trick